# Committed Usage cost more than non-comitted usage Kubernetes Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Through the pricing calculator, the kubernetes engine running on f1-micro (3 years comitted) shows more running cost than non-comitted usage f1-micro.

Is there something wrong with the pricing calculator or Kubernetes Engine automatically switched to standard instance when running comitted usage?

**Comitted usage**

[image: comitted usage]

**Non-comitted usage**

[image: non-comitted usage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can not grab any of the tiers less than n1-standard1 for committed use.](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/signing-up-committed-use-discounts)

> You cannot apply committed use discounts for f1-micro machine types, g1-small machine types, or the sole-tenant premium charge.

I bet the calculator does something silly like, tried to lookup the rules for a micro discount. Since it doesn't apply lists the full price. While the non-commit looks at the monthly hourly rate and determines a sustained use discount(30%) and applies that.